# Android FirebaseAuth getCurrentUser() returns user after fresh install/build

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented an auto-login on my app's start, if the user signed in before and did not log-out. I do this via `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`

Now I build the debug-apk and install this on my physical Android phone. `getCurrentUser()` returns the last user I used on the Android emulator. I really don't want this to happen..

Has anyone an idea how to prevent this ? 
Or why is `FirebaseAuth` doing this ?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that it was a clean install on your physical phone or did you already had the apk installed and updated it? its weird that you also can login in your physical phone when you fresh install the app because there is nothing saved from auth at client side in that phone

Comment: @GastónSaillén Yes, I am sure. I uninstalled the old version multiple times, cleared the app data and cache, etc.

Comment: Are you signed in google account on the phone?

Comment: @Mocas Yes I am. So does Firebase Auth automatically take this as the current user ?

Comment: That is my guess. I would try signing out and check again

Comment: Your guess was right. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out, that `FirebaseAuth` took the signed in Google account from my Android device. 
I removed it in the settings, and `getCurrentUser()` returned null

Comment: Hey ! I'm experiencing the same issue. Could you, please, provide a way to avoid this ?