# FirebaseAuth.getInstance() returns user instead of null on fresh install

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app, I'm trying to check if there is an authenticated user at the beginning, in order to make an annonymous login if not.

The problem is that, if my phone has a google account and it is a fresh install, `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` is not null, as it should.

After reading
[Android FirebaseAuth getCurrentUser() returns user after fresh install/build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380336/android-firebaseauth-getcurrentuser-returns-user-after-fresh-install-build), it looks like Android takes the google account's user in this case.

Is there a way to force FirebaseAuth to not take this account and just say that I'm not authenticated, which is what should be the case here ?

Comment: What do you mean through "it looks like Android takes the google account's user"? Also [Firebase. Anonymous authentication accounts don't persist across application uninstalls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136901/5246885)

Comment: As I'm not already authenticated in the application, currentUser should be null. If I don't have any google account set in my phone, it behaves as it should. But, If I have one, it returns a non-null currentUser, even before any authentication.

"Funny" thing is that if I restart my app, currentUser becomes null again

Comment: Have you ever tryed to authenticate with Google?

Comment: Not in this app. I only use Phone number login